# Smudge fragment shader shows weird circle at the point of the smudge

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to create a "smudge" effect which will essentially push pixels around based on your mouse position. I've been able to get something kind of like what I'm going for, but it shows a circle where the mouse is, like in this screenshot. I'd like for it to just push the pixels up in the curve, but without the circle below the top of the curve:
[image: shadertoy screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my fragment shader:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{      
    vec2 texCoord = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    
    float dist = distance(fragCoord.xy, iMouse.xy);

    vec2 newCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, texCoord.y - 1. / dist);

    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, newCoord);
}
```

And here's my shadertoy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/dltyD7